# Accord KDTree with custom distance function

Tags: c#, geo, kdtree, accord.net

I have a graph data structure representing a road network (nodes are points/intersections in the road and edges are roads). The Node object has a latitude and longitude associated with it.

I'm using Accord's KDTree class to find nearby nodes to a given GPS co-ordinate. Since Accord doesn't seem to have the Haversine distance as a built-in distance function (am I wrong?), I define my own custom distance function, and pass it in as an extra parameter to the KDTree.FromData() method, as follows:

```
        var nodes = graph.Nodes;
        //Initialize KD-tree with distance function defined as the cartesian approximate distance (in meters) 
        Func<double[], double[], double> distanceFunc = (x, y) => DistanceFunctions.ApproximateDistance(x,y);
        kdTreeOfNodes = KDTree.FromData<Node>(nodes.Select(x => new double[] { x.Value.Latitude, x.Value.Longitude }).ToArray(), nodes.ToArray(), distanceFunc);
```

Note that 'ApproximateDistance' is defined as a static method in a separate class, and is a cartesian approximation to the more correct Haversine distance.

I get an exception when attempting to excecute the last line. In this line I pass in the data to put into the KDTree (namely an array of lat/lon arrays) as well as the associated nodes, plus my custom distance function. It seems that this FromData constructor actually (for some reason?) calls my ApproximateDistance function, with the arrays [1] and [1] as the two input parameters, obviously raising an exception since this method expects two 2-dimensional arrays.

I have no idea why this constructor is calling my ApproximateDistance function  (especially with these strange parameters), and can't seem to find out using the debugger...

Comment: What exception do you get?

Comment: Index out of range exception (the ApproximateDistance function expects 2-dimensional arrays, and 1-dimensional arrays are passed in).

Answer (score 3):

K-d-trees do not use point-to-point distances during search until they reach actual data points.

Instead, it's a *one dimensional* deviation, from the splitting plane. Here it would be *either* latitude *or* longitude.

That is the reason why the k-d-tree supports little else than Minkowski norms.

Comment: Right. So you're saying I should have a one-dimensional distance function? That will be problematic for lat / lons, since they technically need seperate distance functions (and longitudinal distance will depend on a "reference latitude" - we can only know the distance associated with a change in longitude if we know what latitude we are at)...
In any case, why is this KDTree constructor actually calling this method? Surely the exception should only crop up once I try use the class?

Comment: Yes. Unless you can decompose your distance into 1d functions, I don't think this will work.

Comment: I don't buy that... Then again I don't properly understand how KD trees work. But Accord has multiple distance functions which can be specified, including e.g. Euclidean distance (which is fundamentally a multi-dimentional distance, and can't be replaced with a 1D distance function...)

Comment: Also, the other question still stands - why is the FromData constructor calling the distance method? Is it inputing its own "test" values or is it using the input data?

Comment: Moreover, about the multi-dimensional distance: the FromData method takes as last parameter a function object of type Func<double[] , double[] , double>, clearly indicating that it expects a multidimensional distance function (otherwise it would have just required an function of type Func<double, double, double>).

Comment: Read up on the kd-tree. All kd-tree implementations I know only support Minkowski norms, or even only Euclidean. I have never used Accord (I don't use any .net) so I have no idea about what it is doing in the constructor. Consult the source code. It probably uses `double[]` for *ease of use*, because the authors did not want to add a function that supports *both* `double[]` (for points) and `double` (for kd-tree only).

Answer (score 1):

The K-d trees in Accord.NET should not have been calling your Distance function unless you are performing a lookup in the tree (i.e. by calling any of the [.Nearest](http://accord-framework.net/docs/html/M_Accord_Collections_KDTreeBase_1_Nearest.htm) or [ApproximateNearest](http://accord-framework.net/docs/html/M_Accord_Collections_KDTreeBase_1_ApproximateNearest.htm) functions). As Anony-Mousse correctly stated, the K-d trees do not use point-to-point distances until they reach actually data points, i.e. when you are performing a search.

[Inspecting the current code](https://github.com/accord-net/framework/blob/development/Sources/Accord.MachineLearning/Collections/KDTree.cs#L229), I couldn't see how the code could possibly be calling ApproximateDistance before the tree is constructed, as you might see that is is only set at the very end of that method.

If you are still experiencing this problem, please register it in the issue tracker, with a small example that triggers the issue, so it could eventually be fixed.

Also, if you need other kinds of trees that rely on point-to-point distances, you might also want to take a look at the recently added [Vantage-Point Trees](http://accord-framework.net/docs/html/T_Accord_Collections_VPTree.htm).

Disclaimer: I am the author of the k-d trees implementation in Accord.NET.

Comment: Thanks for your response! In fact I was looking for nearby edges in the graph, so looking for nearby nodes turned out to be the wrong approach, and I ended up implementing my own grid-based search, which has been working well. 
Anyway, weird about the distance method that was getting called, but I can't replicate the problem anymore at this point. 
P.S. Vantage-Point Trees sound awesome!